# How Do You Create a Single-Select ActionProvider Drop-Down?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want a single-selection list as a drop-down from the action bar. Since `ActionProvider` supports a submenu out of the box, I thought that this would be easy. However, while I can change what the checked item is at the outset (e.g., in `onPrepareSubMenu()`), I cannot change what the checked item is once the submenu is shown. Calls to `setChecked()` have no visual effect.

Here is my `ActionProvider`:

```
/***
 Copyright (c) 2016 CommonsWare, LLC
 Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
 use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy
 of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0. Unless required
 by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the
 License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS
 OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific
 language governing permissions and limitations under the License.

 From _The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development_
 https://commonsware.com/Android
 */

package com.commonsware.android.hurl;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.ActionProvider;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener;
import android.view.SubMenu;
import android.view.View;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SingleChoiceActionProvider extends ActionProvider implements
  OnMenuItemClickListener {
  static final private int[] HTTP_STACKS_ITEM_IDS={
    R.id.hurl,
    R.id.httpclient,
    R.id.httpclient_tor};
  final private MenuInflater inflater;
  final private ArrayList<MenuItem> httpStacksItems=
    new ArrayList<MenuItem>();

  public SingleChoiceActionProvider(Context ctxt) {
    super(ctxt);
    this.inflater=new MenuInflater(ctxt);
  }

  @Override
  public View onCreateActionView() {
    return(null);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean hasSubMenu() {
    return(true);
  }

  @Override
  public void onPrepareSubMenu(SubMenu submenu) {
    submenu.clear();
    httpStacksItems.clear();

    inflater.inflate(R.menu.http_stacks, submenu);
    submenu.setGroupCheckable(R.id.http_stacks, true, true);

    for (int itemId : HTTP_STACKS_ITEM_IDS) {
      MenuItem item=submenu.findItem(itemId);

      httpStacksItems.add(item);
      item.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
/*
    for (MenuItem httpStackItem : httpStacksItems) {
      httpStackItem.setChecked(item==httpStackItem);
    }
*/

    httpStacksItems.get(2).setChecked(true);

    return(true);
  }
}
```

I get control in `onMenuItemClick()` without issue. However, calls to `setChecked()` have no visible effect — whatever item was checked before remains checked. I start off with the first item checked:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <group
    android:id="@+id/http_stacks"
    android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
      android:id="@+id/hurl"
      android:checkable="true"
      android:checked="true"
      android:title="@string/menu_hurl"/>
    <item
      android:id="@+id/httpclient"
      android:checkable="true"
      android:title="@string/menu_httpclient"/>
    <item
      android:id="@+id/httpclient_tor"
      android:checkable="true"
      android:title="@string/menu_httpclient_tor"/>
  </group>
</menu>
```

That first item shows up checked. In theory, tapping any item after that should cause the third one (`get(2)`) to become checked, given my hard-coded hack in `onMenuItemClick()`. Checking the value of `isChecked()` shows that my change is recognized by the `MenuItem`. It's just not changing what's on-screen. Note that calling `setChecked()` in `onPrepareSubMenu()` works correctly, so the problem is limited to once the menu is shown.

Any idea where I am going wrong?

Alternatively, is there another working pattern for implementing this sort of single-select drop-down from an action bar?

Comment: I was playing with the `ActionProvider` in the support library so it might behave differently but aren't you recreating the sub menu each time in `onPrepareSubMenu`? There you clear the submenu and repopulate it so the default will be selected again next time the submenu is shown. Seems like you should remember the previous selection.

Comment: @GeorgeMulligan *::smacks forehead::* Spot on. It's "prepare", not "create". There is no "create" hook for the submenu, which probably contributed to my confusion. I'm still getting odd results (now everything is checked), but that pushes things along. If you post this as an answer, I'll happily accept. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `onPrepareSubMenu()` is called each time the sub menu is displayed. Setting the checked item is working correctly in the `onMenuItemClick` method but the next time the menu is shown the layout is reinflated in `onPrepareSubMenu` so the default item is once again selected.

Also, I think you can get similar results without needing a custom `ActionProvider` by just inflating an item that has a nested menu like so:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/http_stack"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="HTTP Stack">
        <menu>
            <group
                android:id="@+id/http_stacks"
                android:checkableBehavior="single">
            <item
                android:id="@+id/hurl"
                android:checkable="true"
                android:checked="true"
                android:title="@string/menu_hurl"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/httpclient"
                android:checkable="true"
                android:title="@string/menu_httpclient"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/httpclient_tor"
                android:checkable="true"
                android:title="@string/menu_httpclient_tor"/>
            </group>
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

Comment: Hmmm... I'll try the nested menu approach. Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, the nested menu approach works. I wonder what the point is of the submenu stuff in `ActionProvider`. You can't use it if you set an action view, so I don't know what that gains you over just using the nested menu. Anyway, thanks again!